# CASE statement in Join

Tags: sql-server, join, case

```
select col1
from table1
case when @col2 is null then left outer join else join end
table2 on (join condition)
```

Above is my query, I want to choose between left outer or right outer join based on 1 condition.

Is there a better solution for implementing the above problem

Comment: erm, what?.............You can't do that. Please state the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than a perceived solution.

Comment: why would you implement a problem?

Comment: That's (besides being incorrect) selecting between left outer join and an inner join, but you narrative says right outer join. Which is it?

Comment: I want either left outer join or right outer join in a select statement.. that was decided based on  one column checked against null

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking for a `full outer join`? Some sample data and expected results would probably help a *lot* with understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select col1
from table1
left outer join 
table2 on (join condition)
where @col2 is null or (@col2 is not null and table2.id is not null)
```

This will  choose between `left outer` or `inner  join` based on condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is actually possible to do in the manner described... I would write it something like this; so you short-circuit one JOIN based on your additional condition.

```
select col1
  from table1
  left outer join table2
    on (condition)
   and @col2 is null
 right outer join table2
    on (condition)
   and @col2 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:

```
select *
from (
   select 
     Key = 1,
   -- remainder of left outer join 
   union all
   select
     Key=2,
   -- remainder of right outer join
) T
where Key = case when (condition) then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1
from table1 t1 full join table2 t2 on (join condition)
where case when @col2 is null then t2.col1 else t1.col1 end IS NOT NULL
```

You can try this code.